# Change Mac "Ask for password after screensaver" delay

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, bash, applescript

How can I change my Mac OS X Snow Leopard "Ask for password after screensaver" delay?

I've tried:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay -int 3600
```

but won't work. I want to do this through Terminal or AppleScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay -int 3600`

Works for me -- it'll show up as "1 hour" in the preference pane, while `14400` will be "4 hours". You need to consider that the selection in *System Preferences* uses hard-coded selection values, and always uses the next higher value: 61 seconds will show as 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was `-currentHost`.

Comment: Only two files get written by *System Preferences* when changing the value in there: One is `com.apple.screensaver.plist`, the other is the host-specific counterpart in the `ByHost` directory, that contains only settings such as the idle time for the screensaver.