# I want to make Macintosh Security Settings Location-Aware and Automatic

Tags: macos, security, geolocation

I have a Macbook Pro that I take from home to work to coffee shops to hotels. When I am at home, I want it to not require a password except after 4 hours of inactivity. When I am traveling, I want it to require a password after 1 minute, and at work I want it to be 30 minutes.

Is there any software that does this?  Basically, I want to change settings of the Screen Saver based on where I am, and I want it to figure that out automatically based on which Wi-Fi network it's associated to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Marco Polo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) or any of the alternatives described on that page to determine your location (change) and execute a shell script that edits `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist`:

```
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay -int 1800
```

---

Unfortunately, this only takes hold after a re-login. But you can instead use AppleScript for GUI scripting your way through System Preferences:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            tell first window
                tell first tab group
                    # ensure we're on the first tab
                    click (first radio button whose title is "General")

                    # 'require password' checkbox
                    set cb to (first checkbox whose title is "Require password")

                    # 'require password' popup button
                    set pb to pop up button 1

                    # always enable password
                    if value of cb is not 1 then
                        # password is currently disabled, enable it
                        click cb
                    end if

                    # if password is activated now, set the timeout
                    # this check is redundant, you can remove it
                    if value of cb is 1 then
                        # click pop up button to get menu
                        click pop up button 1

                        # select 'immedately'
                        click first menu item of menu of pb
                    end if
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

Create three versions of this script for each desired selection from the popup-menu. `first menu item` is immediately, `second menu item` is 5 seconds, and so on.

Save them as script, e.g. `immediately.scpt,` and execute using `osascript` from the command line, or save as application from AppleScript Editor, and execute by `open`ing them.

Depends on which solution for determining your location you decide to use.

Comment: [Related post](http://superuser.com/questions/256502/change-mac-ask-for-password-after-screensaver-delay).

Comment: Wow. That is amazing. Thanks so much. I really, really need to learn how AppleScript works.

Comment: Have you found MarcoPolo to run on 10.6?

Comment: @vy32 The web page I linked to discusses issues with 10.6 and links to a google groups discussion where someone offers a patched version that supposedly fixes WiFi issues.

Answer (score 0):

[AirPort Location](http://airportlocation.wordpress.com/) can snapshot per-location system settings and re-apply them when you use the machine at that location.  Check it out to see if it can include the settings you need.

Comment: It can configure *Screen Saver Lock* but I was unable to have it change the value to far.